# Prove or disprove ring $\mathbb{C}\times \mathbb{C}$ and ring Quaternion $H$ are isomorphic

Tags: quaternions, ring-isomorphism

My attempt: let $f$ ($w$+$x$**i**+$y$**j**+$z$**k**) $=$ ($w$+$x$**i**,$y$+$z$**i**)

then I tried proving it is a homomorphism. $f$ is a homomorphism under addition but fails to be a homomorphism under multiplication.

Can anyone give any hint? Or any property I need to show they don't share.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What multiplication did you define on $\mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C}$?

Comment: @Harnak I'm not sure. I used $ (a, b)(c, d) = (ac, bd）$ for $a,b,c,d$  in $C$

Comment: You are trying to prove that they are isomorphic with respect to which structure?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos They are both rings, I have edited it.

Comment: Then you did you use the `group-isomorphism` tag?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Sorry.

Comment: Hint: The quaternions have several properties for which they are famous. The other ring will have none of these.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I don't know much about quaternions, can you give some examples for those properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are not isomorphic because $\mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{C}$ is commutative, whereas $\mathbb H$ is not.

Comment: How did you define multiplication on  $\mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C}$ ? Sorry I'm new to this topic.

Comment: I used the one that you mentioned in the comments: $(a,b)\times(c,d)=(ac,bd)$.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

To have a ring isomorphism you need to give $\mathbb{C}^2$ the following ring structure:
$$(a,b)+(c,d) = (a+c,b+d)$$
$$(a,b)(c,d) = (ac - \bar{d}b, da + b \bar{c})$$
in which case the isomorphism is given by:
$$x + yi + zj + wk \mapsto (x + yi, z + wi)$$
It doesn't work with the product you mentioned in the comments above.

For more information, you can check on [Cayley-Dickson construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Dickson_construction).

Comment: Thank you. In this question, do we always need to give a new ring structure or use the multiplication I mentioned above by default ?

Comment: That depends on what you have to do. There is no standard product in $\mathbb{C}^2$. If you want them to be ring-isomorphic, however, you have to define the product I mentioned.